# Can cloud-based approaches like Azure be described as 'environmentally friendly'?

Tags: cloud, azure

I'm responding to a Request for Proposals for a new insurance implementation. In my response I state that the "the elastic approach allows us to scale-down during periods of low demand, thus providing a solution that is not only cost-effective, but also environmentally friendly; there are no servers idling and wasting power at night when demand is low"

My boss quite rightly pointed out that the hardware in the cloud data centre that ran our scaled-back instances is probably still running, therefore are we making a valid point?

So I'm wondering - is 'environmentally friendly' a valid argument for a scalable cloud-based solution? Do Microsoft ever switch off Azure servers when the demand is low?

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the amount of servers used by individual companies may be seen as Environment Friendly, as the amount of CO2 being produced by the servers of each company is thereby decreased.

Then again if all these companies were to move to cloud based servers, the amount of servers that need to maintain the cloud will also need to increase, thereby again producing more CO2.  So we are back to square one.

In my company we never switch off our servers, even if there is no demand. Interesting question!!